# Compare second column of two text files and print first columns of both files if match

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, join

I am trying to compare second columns of two text files and print the first columns of both files if match.

I have tried the below `awk` codes but it was no use

```
1) awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$2; next} {print $1,a[$1]}' nid8.txt nid9.txt

2) awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$2; next} {print $1, $1 in a}' nid8.txt nid9.txt
```

Example files:

**nid8.txt:**

```
1000 500
1001 501
1002 502
1003 503
1004 504
1005 505
```

**nid9.txt:**

```
2000 504
2001 502
2002 508
2003 505
2004 500
2005 501
```

**Output:**

```
1000 2004
1001 2005
1002 2001
1004 2000
1005 2003
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` here:

```
join -j 2 -o 1.1 2.1 <(sort -nk2,2 nid8.txt) <(sort -nk2,2 nid9.txt)
```

Use the second field `-j 2` on both files as the keys.

and `-o`utput these fields:
first field from the first file `1.1`
first field from the second file `2.1`

`join` requires input files to be sorted, so we sort them on the second field that will be used as the key numerically `sort -nk2,2 input`.

---

Using `awk` which not require to have sorted inputs but load first input file into memory:

```
awk '!second_file{ my_array[$2]=$1; next }
     ($2 in my_array) { print $1, my_array[$2] }' nid8.txt second_file=1 nid9.txt
```

with `my_array[$2]=$1` we are saving first column of first input file *nid8.txt*  only where the keys are the second column of the same first file until `second_file` variable value is not set to *1* which cause `!second_file` expression value evaluate to false and won't execute that block for next input(s).

With `($2 in my_array)` condition we checks if the second field exist in our array *my_array* or not, if that was exist then we print first field `$1`  (which is from the second file) and the value for that same key with `my_array[$2]` which contains the first field from the first file with the *same key*.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question and also for the answer. I used the awk code and it worked. So if I understood, my_array automatically has both columns of the second file. and $2 key has the 1st column? the code starts to execute from $2 in my_array and checks if current file $2 is in the my_array if yes. it prints $1 of the current file and definition of my_array[$2] from the previous line.?

Comment: @ash emm, no, please see my edit on answer